# Accessing SQL Server database from multiple webpages through asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, vb.net

I am a new developer.

I have a problem of creating a website that needs to access one user account and retrieve all his information in that database through different webpages like one page for viewing his profile data; another page to view the exams that he already created ... etc.

What I did was for each single aspx page I had to create a new object and connect to the SQL Server database from that object which I feel there's something wrong with that.

The question is there any way that I can define the database object only once and make it accessible from different webpages in the same website and execute SQL queries from that object and retrieve data?

Thanks

Comment: Look at ORM and Repository Pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use this implementation using MVC...maybe you could adapt it to your needs:

**clsConnectionManager**

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.Configuration
Imports System.Data

Public Class clsConnectionManager

Implements IDisposable
<ThreadStatic> _
Private Shared pSqlConnection As SqlConnection
Private Shared pConnectionString As String

Public Shared ReadOnly Property Connection() As SqlConnection
    Get
        If pSqlConnection Is Nothing Then
            pConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DefaultConnection").ConnectionString
            pSqlConnection = New SqlConnection(pConnectionString)
            pSqlConnection.Open()
        End If

        If pSqlConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            pSqlConnection.Open()
        End If

        Return pSqlConnection
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub Dispose() Implements System.IDisposable.Dispose
    If pSqlConnection IsNot Nothing Then
        pSqlConnection.Close()
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

**Web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=yourDBName;User ID=YourDBUserName;Password=YourUserPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**Use**

Inside your classes you could do something like this:

```
Public Sub dbGetAll()
        Try
            Using New clsConnectionManager()

                Using lObjSQLCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("StoredProcedureName", clsConnectionManager.Connection)
                    lObjSQLCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    Using lObjSqlDataReader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = lObjSQLCommand.ExecuteReader()
                        Do While lObjSqlDataReader.Read()
                            /*Read rows...*/
                        Loop
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: That's really what I have been searching for !! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can define the connection settings in the web.config file and access the same in your.aspx page.
Refer http://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/